# Json parsing and mapping keys

Tags: json, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I'm trying to map json to send it to another applications which expects the data in it's own formats, I'm using the AWS Lambda which when an event is triggered GETs below json which needs to be parsed and mapped according to what application expects. but the key stack is so large eg "rateCode" in "ratePlan" in "Details", there are almost 20000 rate codes like "abc", "xyz",... it is not a great idea to map like

```
if "rateCode" == "abc":
    application_two_dict["rate_code"] = 123
```

so there are many more keys which keys has large set of values. what is the best way to map those keys. Also this needs to be happened in two way like when we get data from application two we need the parse the json and map the keys other way around which application one understands and vice versa.

```
{
    "customer": {
        "firstName": "john",
        "lastName": "doe",
        "email": "john.doe@test.com",
        "mailingAddress": {
            "address1": "123 N 1st st",
            "address2": "789",
            "countryCode": "USA",
            "stateCode": "AZ",
            "city": "Phoenix",
            "postalCode": "34567"
        },
        "telephoneNumber": {
            "telephoneNumber": "1235456789"
        }
    },
    "paymentAccount": {
        "firstName": "john",
        "lastName": "doe",
        "paymentAccountType": "VA",
        "expirationDate": "2021-05-31",
        "billingAddress": {
            "address1": "1234 N 1st st",
            "address2": "435",
            "city": "Phoenix",
            "countryCode": "USA",
            "postalCode": "213445",
            "stateCode": "AZ"
        }
    },
    "Details": {
        "123": [{
            "quantity": 1,
            "ratePlan": {
                "rateCode": "abc",
                "DetailsList": [{
                    "CategoryCode": "1234",
                }]
            }
    }
}
```

I still don't have the exact format of app2 json

example json

for example

app1 json

```
{
 "Details": {
        "123": [{
            "quantity": 1,
            "ratePlan": {
                "rateCode": "abc",
                "DetailsList": [{
                    "CategoryCode": "1234",
                }]
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

app 2 json

```
{
    user_details_code : 123,
    quantity : [1],
    rate_plan : {
        rate_code: "xyz",
        category_code : "US_SAN"
    }
}
```

Comment: Method 1:Create a table with a partition key (named **app1rateCode** for instance) that contains app1 rateCode values. Store app2 rateCode in the table as an attribute named **app2rateCode**. Create a GSI and use the app2rateCode attribute as the partition key to the index. That way, you can query

Comment: Method 2 (which I prefer):
Create a table with a partition key (named **rateCode** for instance) that contains app1 and app2 rateCode values and a sort key (named app for instance) that contains static values ("app1" and "app2" only). You can then store  the rateCode in an attribute that you can name OtherRateCode.
You can query rateCode using the partition key and specifying the app you want to fetch corresponding code from using the sort key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try the following ways:
- use two static map with rateCode as keys

{ "abc": "123", ...} and { "123": "abc", ...} and use them to get values from the other app rateCode value.

- use a database to fetch rateCode for app2 based on app1 value. Dynamo has a very low latency and can be very effective.

Maybe you could describe more precisely the json structure of the two apps.

Comment: Thanks Brice. I'm still waiting from other team to give the app2 json. using Dynamo DB do I need to store the key value pair as app1 and app2 keys and how does the reverse mapping happens when sending the data from app2 to app1 ?

Comment: for example 

app1 json

`
{
 "Details": {
        "123": [{
            "quantity": 1,
            "ratePlan": {
                "rateCode": "abc",
                "DetailsList": [{
                    "CategoryCode": "1234",
                }]
            }
        }
    }   
}
`


app 2 json

`
{
 user_details_code : 123,
 quantity : [1],
 rate_plan : {
  rate_code: "xyz",
  category_code : "US_SAN"
 }
}

`